# Theme installation numix (local installation)

Tags: 16.04, themes

I was trying to figure out how to install a popular theme called "Numix". The thing was I wanted to install it locally, without adding a ppa, .deb file, etc. I found out how to do so (thanks to you fellow Ubuntu users!)

The think was I tried downloading the theme from their github page, extracted it and looked for the theme file. I could not find out how to install it it was setup differently. I found a folder that looked like the right folder but it didn't work all the way, for some reason it only showed up half way.

[image: Screenshot]

So I contacted them on github and they told me I can do so by running some commands. I have no idea what it does or how it works. I'm guessing I have to build it? I have no idea. But when looking at it I noticed a part of it says **"Execute from repo root"** in it. This concerns me and makes me wonder, "Is this using root privileges"?

[You can find the files I downloaded here.](https://github.com/numixproject/numix-gtk-theme)

[Here's the Github issue page I posted on.](https://github.com/numixproject/numix-gtk-theme/issues/685)

**Here's the command or script he gave me:**

```
# Execute from repo root
scss --update --sourcemap=none src/gtk-3.20/scss:src/gtk-3.20/dist
glib-compile-resources --sourcedir=src/gtk-3.20 src/gtk-3.20/gtk.gresource.xml
./scripts/utils.sh install ~/.local/share/themes/Numix/
```

How is this installing it locally? Are the commands he gave me safe? Anyways I'm lost, I have no idea why he said this or what this does. If this is building something I have no idea. I'm illiterate when it comes to building anything. I would appreciate any feedback you guys can give me. Thanks!

**By the way let me know if I used the wrong folder after the file extraction etc.**

Comment: `Execute from repo root` I believe means you run that command in the `root folder` of that repo not `execute as root`

Comment: I agree to @George. It's usual when we need to compile some package to begin and execute commands  at root package folder, to grant everything will be done.

Comment: So this is installing it locally and it's safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement `Execute from repo root` simply means you should run that command from the `root folder` of the cloned repo and not doesn't mean `run that command as root`

Lets look at that command:

```
# Execute from repo root
scss --update --sourcemap=none src/gtk-3.20/scss:src/gtk-3.20/dist
glib-compile-resources --sourcedir=src/gtk-3.20 src/gtk-3.20/gtk.gresource.xml
./scripts/utils.sh install ~/.local/share/themes/Numix/
```

This `install ~/.local/share/themes/Numix/` I believe directs it to be installed in your `home` folder and that doesn't need `root privileges` to do so.